# 2.8" Resistive PiTFT plus not working with Raspberry Pi 3 and Retropie

Tags: pi-3, retropie, emulation, pitft

I'm using all the same parts in [Adafruit's Pigrrl 2 build](https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-2/overview) except its a Pi3 instead of a Pi2.

I got The TFT screen to work when I turn on the raspberry pi. It starts in command prompt and it's running Rasbian Jessie. My issue is that I I manually installed emulation station and Retropie but when I run "Emulationstation" the screen goes black and just has a cursor in the corner and never shows anything else.

The screen in question is this one: https://www.adafruit.com/products/2298

Comment: Please add links to the said display.

Comment: @Nasha I added the links to the original post above

Comment: Try asking this question in one of the Adafruit fora; if you are lucky, one of their people will answer it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Should I delete it from here too though?

Comment: I just asked on adafruit forum here too: http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=95629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working. I followed [this guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/running-opengl-based-games-and-emulators-on-adafruit-pitft-displays?view=all#retropie-setup) basically.

Had to start clean with the newest version of Retropie for Rasb Pi 3. Then used HDMI connection to set it up part way and then added TFT screen and continued setup through SSH from my laptop. Now I just need to get the buttons working...